# Missing QtWebKit headers + modules

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I'm a newcomer to Qt and I'm having a hard time embedding a web browser control in my application.

- When I try to `#include <QtWebKit>` or `#include <QWebView>`, the compiler complains that neither of those header files exist. The same goes for `QtWebKitWidgets`, as well.
- When I add `QT += webkit` or `QT += webkitwidgets` in my qmake `.pro` file, I get an error saying `Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit`.

How do I install these modules / headers so I can use `QWebView` in my application? (My Qt version is 5.2.1.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to install **qtwebkit** from repository.

On Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libqt5webkit5

On ArchLinux: [sudo pacman -S qtwebkit](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/qtwebkit/)

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing your distro's QtWebKit dev package. Double check that you have the headers. A good command for this is `find /usr/include -iname "*qtwebkit*"`. You should get some files back, one of them should be called `QtWebKit`, and if you open it in a text editor, you should see the text of the header.

In some distributions, the QtWebKit headers are in a separate package from the base Qt development files. Make sure you have that package installed if applicable. I know that in Arch Linux and Manjaro, the packages you need are `qt5-base` and `qt5-webkit`, and if I remember correctly, Debian-based distros (Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc) call those packages `qtbase5-dev` and `libqt5webkit5-dev`.

If you are missing the package and need help finding it for your distribution, you can try asking over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).